# How do chests in Dust an Elysian tail decide what to drop?

Tags: dust-an-elysian-tail

I have played dust for a while and wondered if chest drops were random. If they are, then do they choose completely random items, or choose from a list of possible drops? If not, then what does each chest drop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After trying to open a few chests, reloading and opening them again, I can confirm that they all have preset drops in both gold and blueprints.

Comment: Thank you, but it is kinda important to me to find what chest drops what.

Comment: Don't think the game is popular enough for someone to do a complete loot guide though.

Comment: Oh well, one can only hope...